# Java, display chm file loaded from resources in jar

Tags: java, resources, chm

I am trying to display the chm file containing the help which is loaded from resources:

```
try  
{
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/help.chm");

    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);       //Exception 
} 

catch (Exception e) 
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When the project is run from NetBeans, the help file is displayed correctly. 
Unfortunately, it does not work, when the program is run from the jar file; it leads to an exception.

In my opinion, the internal structure of jar described by URI has not  been recognized... Is there any better way? For example, using the BufferReader class?

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

An analogous problem with the jpg file has been fixed with the BufferedImage class

```
BufferedImage img = null;
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/test.jpg");
if (url!= null)
{
     img = ImageIO.read(url);
}
```

without any conversion to URI...

Thanks for your help...

Comment: A .jar file is a zip file with a different extension.  An entry in a .jar file is not itself a file, and trying to create a File object from a .jar resource URL will *never* work.  Use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) and [copy the stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) to a temporary file.

Comment: @ VGR: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it can probably not be done. The program will be run as Java Web Start application, some additional  rights will be required (or not?)...

Comment: If you have permission to execute Desktop.open, I think you will have permission to [create a temporary file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).

Comment: @ VGR : May I ask you for an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .jar file is a zip file with a different extension. An entry in a .jar file is not itself a file, and trying to create a File object from a .jar resource URL will never work. Use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) and copy the stream to a temporary file:

```
Path chmPath = Files.createTempFile(null, ".chm");

try (InputStream chmResource =
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/help.chm")) {

    Files.copy(chmResource, chmPath,
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

Desktop.getDesktop().open(chmPath.toFile());
```

As an alternative, depending on how simple your help content is, you could just store it as a single HTML file, and pass the resource URL to a non-editable JEditorPane.  If you want to have a table of contents, an index, and searching, you might want to consider learning how to use [JavaHelp](https://javahelp.java.net).

Comment: @ VGR, thank you very much, it works... However, is it a common way how to work with chm files? What about some more "direct" approach than the temporary file? :-)

Comment: A .jar file is a zip archive.  Its entries are not separate files, period.  There isn’t a more direct way.